# MySQL get min number in distinct query

Tags: mysql

I have this query here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, name, community, mapLocation, logo FROM `ourCommunity` INNER JOIN readyBuilt ON community = home_community WHERE home_new = "yes" AND isDeleted = 0 AND is_upcoming = 0
```

and this returns 7 results, when I try to get each items min price from the readyBuilt table it only returns 1 item, not 7 :( I tried this MIN(price) what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The INNER JOIN keyword selects all rows from both tables as long as there is a match between the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select min(price),id,name,community,maplocation where id in (
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM `ourCommunity` INNER JOIN readyBuilt ON community = home_community WHERE home_new = "yes" AND isDeleted = 0 AND is_upcoming = 0)

Comment: there is a syntax error somewhere here `where id in ( SELECT DISTINCT id FROM ourCommunity INNER JOIN readyBuilt ON comm'`

Comment: Try adding on a group by. it's probably not liking the min function with the rest of the fields. select min(price),id,name,community,maplocation where id in ( SELECT DISTINCT id FROM ourCommunity INNER JOIN readyBuilt ON community = home_community WHERE home_new = "yes" AND isDeleted = 0 AND is_upcoming = 0) group by id,name,community, maplocation